# Applying binomial distribution

Tags: probability

a) According to a simple model for how a web searcher visits search results there is always 60% chance that the searcher will visit any search result. The model assumes that the visit of any search result does not affect whether any other search result is visited. For 10 search results, answer the following:

i) What is the probability that the searcher will visit between 1 and 9 search results?

ii) What is the probability that the searcher will visit 2 or 3 search results?

### P(X=x) = C(n,x)P^x(1-P)^n-x

(i) 
Where I substituted

n = 10

x = 7

p = 0.6

Where I get 0.215, Is this the correct way to do it?

ii)

n = 10

x = 2

p = 0.6

and

n = 10

x = 1

p = 0.6

I added the two combinations and got 0.0503

Can someone confirm if this is correct?
Thank you! (:

Comment: Why did you choose (i)  $x=7$ and (ii) $x=2$ and $x=1$ ?

Comment: between 1 and 9, so 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: No, @RedCactus . The event is "the count of results visited is between 1 and 9", *not* that "the searcher visits the 7 results between the first and ninth".

Comment: so x would be equal to 9? and then for part 2 its because the amount of searches?

Comment: Find $\mathsf P(1\leq X\leq 9)\qquad$ Hint: $\mathsf P(1\leq X\leq 9) = 1-\mathsf P(X=0\cup X=10)$

Comment: Oh so i work out the probability the searcher will visit 10, and subtract 1 - from that. So x = 10.

Comment: That is: Ten, or Zero.

Comment: Ohh alright thank you and I just add the two probabilities together?

Comment: Add together, and subtract that sum from one, yes.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamKemp what about part 2 is that correct?

Comment: Likewise, you want $\mathsf P(X\in\{2,3\}) ~=~ \mathsf P(X=2)+\mathsf P(X=3)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes, sorry I did compute with 2 and 3 the typo was the 1